# "undo" goes to int() what shouldn't have happened

Tags: python

I have one problem. While drawing some sprites, why do I have a string named "undo" that goes to int()? (base 10)

```
import win32gui as w
import os as r
import time as t
import keyboard as kb
import random as ra
fw = w.GetForegroundWindow()
con = w.GetDC(fw)
r.system(f'mode con:cols={64} lines={32}')
r.system('color 07')
def CreateImag(readedlines,x,y):
    for u in readedlines:
        gg=u.split()
        w.BitBlt(con,int(gg[0])+x,int(gg[1])+y,int(gg[2]),int(gg[3]),con,0,0,-1)
print('sprite draw')
t.sleep(2)
rl = []
r.system('cls')
while True:
    print("\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n"+'='*64+"\n [from x from y f.x+x", end='')
    print("f.y+y], for exit type \"exit\", for undo type \"undo\"")
    if ag=='undo':
        print(list.pop(-1))
        break
    ag = input('>>')
    if ag=='exit':
        file = open(f'image{ra.randint(0,100001)}.imag')
        for aa in rl:
            file.write(f'{aa}\n')
        file.close()
    rl.append(ag)
    CreateImag(rl, 10, 10)
    r.system('cls')
```

> and then it gives this
> [image: %%%]

Why is the string not appending?

Comment: Did you try `print(gg)`? It will be something like `["undo"]`. And then you do `int(gg[0])` so that translates to `int("undo")`

Comment: You want to remove items from `rl` list when the entered text is `undo` so that should be `rl.pop()` not `list.pop()`. Also you probably what to do this operation  after reading input. Ensure to handle for `IndexError` raise when `rl` is an empty list.

Comment: @OluwafemiSule i'm about a last string in list. we have `['0 0 10 10', '10 10 10 10']`, and how i delete this? like `list[-...]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I read the code and tried to understand the goal of the program, and here are the things I figured out that is done wrong. I stated them and provided solutions for them.

### 1

The reason why `ag=input()` is written after the `if` statement is because you cannot execute the undo command without doing anything. So, you need to do something first, and only then you can undo.

So, the error is caused, which is shown from the terminal pic is because, by you entering **'undo' as the first command**, and since it didn't find any *if* statement, it appended the string 'undo' to `rl` (Which is not what we want).

**Solution:**

**First,** don't enter 'undo' as the first command in the program. *(Although, it's the most easy fix but not recommended practice.)*

**Second,** Shift the `ag=input(">>")` command directly under two `print` statements and change the code in the `if` statement as follows:

```
if ag=='undo':
    if len(rl) > 0: # Condition to check if rl is not empty
        print(rl.pop(-1))
        break # Use continue instead?
```

*I changed `list.pop(-1` to `rl.pop(-1)` as recommended by @oluwafemi-sule*

**Advice/Recommendation**: Usually, when we undo things we don't exit the program/loop. We generally don't break the loop. We skip the rest of the execution, so I fell you should use `continue` instead of `break` in the above code.

---

### 2

Suppose someone entered 'exit' instead of the required argument, hence the program performs the required steps before closing. Now, we want the program to terminate, and here in your code there is no termination statement.

If we don't terminate the program, 'exit' will  be appended to the `rl` and again it'll cause an error. Hence, your other `if` statement should have a `break` statement. That would break the loop and hence complete the execution.

```
if ag=='exit':
    file = open(f'image{ra.randint(0,100001)}.imag')
    for aa in rl:
        file.write(f'{aa}\n')
    file.close()
    break
```